# About deleting Nodes

Tags: c++, memory-management, nodes

I understand what these lines of code are doing and it seems to work right when I want to `delete` a `Node`.

```
temp = current->next;
current->next = current->next->next;
delete temp;
```

However, can someone explain to me what exactly happens if you do:

```
delete current->next;
current->next = current->next->next;
```

I may be "overthinking" it but when I `delete current->next`, am I deleting the contents that next is pointing to or the pointer `next`? Because when I do the second bit of code I obviously get an error.
But, why is it that I can't change what `next` points to after I `delete` whatever `current->next` *was* pointing to? I just want to get a solid understanding of what I am doing.

Comment: There error isn't that you try to give it a new value. It is the new value that you try to give it involves you going through the node you just deleted!

Comment: Oh of course! If that's the case then I suppose it makes perfect sense now! :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've called `delete` there is no requirement for the memory to contain anything valid. It may be that the deleted data is still the same as it was before you called `delete`, but that's undefined behaviour, and you can't depend upon it.

Because you can depend on the data being valid any attempt to read it will either give you back garbage or cause some form of access violation.

Answer (score 0):

You use pointers to reference a region of memory allocated at the *free store* (also known as the *heap*, although the terms refer to different places).

Suppose you say something like

```
int* p = new int{42};
```

What happens here is that a block of memory of at least `sizeof(int)` bytes is reserved *somewhere*, and you use variable `p` to refer to it. Please note that the region of memory doesn't really have a name; you merely use `p` to manipulate its contents.

Now well, when you say

```
delete p;
```

you are not deleting `p`, but rather *the region of memory that `p` refers to*. You can (in theory) use `p` after the above statement, but any attempt to dereference it will result in undefined behavior.

In your case,

```
delete current->next;
```

causes the region of memory referenced by this pointer to be deallocated, and as such the next statement

```
current->next = current->next->next;
```

isn't a great idea, because `current->next` isn't valid anymore.